Can I visit the UK for one week with a Pakistani passport and a 10-year French resident card?
I have a 10-year French resident card and a Pakistani passport. Can I travel to the UK for one week without a visa, accompanied by my French husband and our French children?

I have edited the title and body of your question to improve its clarity, and have tried to leave your questions unchanged. If you disagree with my changes, you can change the wording back to what you originally wrote by selecting the "edited by" text above my name, followed by selecting the "revert" button.

Do you hold a carte de résident or carte de séjour membre de famille d'un Européen (the latter is confusingly called an article 10 “residence card” in English)?

Neither your status in France nor your relationship with a French citizen exempts you from any visa requirement to enter the UK. The only way in which EU freedom of movement law could have an impact is if you and your spouse had been living in the UK before 2020 but this doesn't seem to be the case. As a Pakistani citizen, you will therefore need to apply for a Standard visitor visa.
As French citizens, your husband and children do not need a visa for the same visit but they need a passport (a carte d'identité is not enough).
That's not relevant for this trip but note that your French residence permit does exempt you from the Direct Airside Transit visa Pakistani citizens have to get for a layover at a UK airport.

Wait, are you saying that spouses of EU citizens with "settled status" in the UK still get some special treatment today? Really? That's surprisingly reasonable.

@terdon - clearly an oversight by the Home Office...

UK is not in European Union anymore. So, the freedom of movement option does not apply. You have to apply for visa.
Considering your situation, it will be very easy and straight forward to get a UK visa.
From TIMATIC

Passengers who are the family member of an EU, EEA, or Swiss national
travelling to the United Kingdom must hold an EU Settlement Scheme
family permit, a UK issued EEA family permit, or a UK issued biometric
residence card.
These passengers are not permitted to use an Article 10 or 20
residence card issued by an EEA member state.


The OP said (in their original text) that they had a "10 years valid residence card." Is this card the same as an "EU Settlement Scheme family permit" ? Is this card the same as an "Article 10 or 20 residence card issued by an EEA member state" ? If it is the first, and is not the second, then the answer is correct. If it is not the first and is either an Article 10 or 20 card, then the answer is incorrect.

@DavidRecallsMonica The OP has a residence card (Article 10/20) issued in France (a EEA member state). It is not the same as a UK based 'EU Settlement Scheme' family permit (a result of Brexit). The answer is correct.

This is the one OP was supposed to apply - https://www.gov.uk/settled-status-eu-citizens-families/join-EU-EEA-Swiss-family-member . OP obviously doesn't qualify.

@MarkJohnson Why do you think so? Nothing suggests it.

@DavidRecallsMonica Most likely, it's neither. The answer is correct that the freedom of movement wouldn't cover the OP anymore but the TIMATIC excerpt is irrelevant and they are not entitled to an easier visa.

OK, I see where the confusion in the comments and answer comes from. Carte de résident is the French name for a 10-year permanent residence permit (as opposed to a carte de séjour, which is a renewable 1-4 year permit), @MarkJohnson basically the French equivalent to a Niederlassungserlaubnis. For a third-country national residing in France with their French spouse, EU law would not usually be relevant, this is in all likelihood a regular French residence permit, not a residence card under directive 2004/38/EC.

@DavidRecallsMonica an "EU Settlement Scheme family permit" is a document issued by the UK for EU citizens in the "EU Settlement Scheme" (mostly people who resided in the UK for years before Brexit without any need for additional paperwork, and no longer were able to do so after Brexit). It is not a document issued by the EU or any EU country. If OP had the former, they would be living in the UK. The quote from Timatic means if you have the former then you can enter (as you are a UK resident, basically). If you have a EU residence card, you can't enter, and need a visa.
